# I need some type of ceiling in the downstairs bathroom that will allow me access to the pipes.

Tags: bathroom, ceiling, waterproofing

What would be the best way to go about this? It must be able to withstand moisture.
I have seen vinyl ceiling tiles for a drop ceiling but there is not really a lot of head room (90"). The over all area is 97 x 110 and there will be a jacuzzi tub there.

Answer (score 1):

I have used tin squares on basements and you could get screws that match the tin finish.

Comment: Did you attach directly to the joists?

Comment: Yep.  Had to put some crosses in every once in a while.  It is a really good look but the tins that look seem to cost a bit.  Also if you can get hex head screws in same finish it can look really good - I have been able to do this with stainless steel and satin.

Comment: You have to figure tins are perfect here because the go with a bathroom and can take a little water on them.

Comment: There are also vinyl [tin-look panels](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Ceilume-Fleur-de-lis-White-2-ft-x-2-ft-Lay-in-or-Glue-up-Ceiling-Panel-Case-of-6-V3-FLEUR-22WTO/203469186) that give a similar appearance but are more water resistant.